# transform function not working angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I try to call angular function in `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.gagSlider();
  }
```

gagSlider() function

```
gagSlider(){
    $.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, complete) {
        alert(1);
        return this.each(function() {
          var $elem = $(this);

          $({deg: 0}).animate({deg: angle}, {
            duration: duration,
            easing: easing,
            step: function(now) {
              $elem.css({
                 transform: 'rotate(' + (-90 + ((90 * 180) / 100)) + 'deg)'
               });
            },
            complete: complete || $.noop
          });
        });
      };

      $('.meter-clock').animateRotate(0);
}
```

I am getting alert successfully but rotate not working

Comment: Did you try to use Angular Animation instead of JQuery ?

Comment: No friend.. any help highly appreciated

Comment: Can you explain what your animation need to exactly do ? To look if  it's not possible to do it directly by CSS with class switching using ngClass.

Comment: Speedometer like animation example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRjqYj